# Android download XML and fill a list with specific values from the XML?

Tags: android, xml, listview

Using Android (write own app) I would like to download an XML file

```
<magazines>
<magazine>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <downloadlink>http://example.com/pdf1.pdf</downloadlink>
</magazine>
<magazine>
    <title>Hello2</title>
    <downloadlink>http://example.com/pdf2.pdf</downloadlink>
</magazine>
<magazine>
    <title>Hello3</title>
    <downloadlink>http://example.com/pdf3.pdf</downloadlink>
</magazine>
<magazine>
    <title>Hello4</title>
    <downloadlink>http://example.com/pdf4.pdf</downloadlink>
</magazine>
```

Then fill an Android ListView with the title and download link.

How would I go about doing this? (Would be breese with c#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope [this](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser/) helps!

Comment: Wish Android supported Mono fully, so we can use LINQ